# how to add ocx files in vb4.0 (I am migrating from vb4 to vb6

Tags: vb6

I am migrating vb4 application to vb6.0 app. I am using windows xp. I want to add ocx controls to the application. Any simple steps to do add ocx controls/files to the application. What are .frm files

```
Object = "{bla-lablabla-lablabla}#2.0#0"; "THREED20.OCX"
Object = "{blabla-bla-bla-blabla-blablabla}#2.0#0"; "vsview2.ocx"
```

I want to add these two ocx controls in vb6  ( 16 bit to 32 bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't state if you already have the `OCX` files.

To address your first question on how to add `OCX` controls to your `VB6` project. You need to go to Projects -->Components( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> ) then click the Browse button and navigate to where the `OCX` is located and select it.

As far as the actual `OCX` Files are concerned there is a `Threed20.ocx` that is included on the VB6 install media, I believe it is on Disk 2. There is also a registry file that you will need to run to enable design time use of the control.  As far as the `vsview2.ocx` file is concerned  if it is not a 32 bit OCX you will need to contact the vendor, who I believe is [`ComponentSource`](http://www.componentsource.com/products/componentone-vsview-classic/index.html) to get the proper version if you don't currently have it.

And as far is what is a `.frm` file it is [according to this article](http://ecomputernotes.com/visual-basic/basic-of-visual-basic/what-is-the-purpose-of-visual-basic-file-types-vbp-frm-bas-and-ocx)

> A form holds the description of all objects and their properties for each form, as well as the basic code that you have written to respond to the events.